# OOP inheritance loop

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

i have two object with the structure like this:

```
class A extends anotherClass{

 public __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->products = new B();
 }

 public function a(){
 }

}

class B extends A{


 public function b(){

 }

}
```

I need to use a method from each object in the other object,but this gives me exhausted memory error,besides the fact that is an ugly way of doing it,but that's all i could come up with.
I've looked around the google a bit and found something like this:

```
$first = class A();
$second = class B($first);


class B extends A{
    public $firstclass;
    public __construct($class){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->firstclass = $class;
     }

     public function b(){

     }

}
```

But this too,doesn't look too good,though it works.

Comment: Why would you want to add 'recursiveness' like this?

Comment: Actually,it's not a matter of 'want' but rather limited by my little knowledge of oop.. If you have a better idea on how to structure this,it would be much apreciated

Comment: Though i can't change the fact that there is 1 method in each object ,which i need in the other object

Comment: In your example it seems B is of a different functionality than A. Then don't try to extend it from A unless it looks very much alike. If you need a lot of functionality that looks like A, but isn't, then create a base class that both A and B extend from... Makes more sense... But B tries to instantiate an object similar to itself in its scope, so that's why you get the out of memory

Comment: your are creating a infinite loop that way exhausted memory. this does not make any sense, change your logic or be more specific

Comment: @PeterCos is there any reason, why your `B` class needs to inherit all the functionality of `A` class **and** `anotherClass`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a recursion but an endless loop that you end up with

I think your main problem stems from the abuse (or maybe - misunderstanding) of `extends` keyword. When you have code `class Foo extends Bar`, you should read it as one of the following:

- every instance of `Foo` **is a** special case of `Bar`
- all instances of `Foo` **behave like** instances of `Bar`

> <sub>**Note:** the second version is considered to be a better one, **but**
>    its implications are probably to complex for a newbie. If you are interested,
>    it is touched upon in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMuno5RZNeE&t=259s).</sub>

In a well written object-oriented code you would not see any deep inheritance trees (for detailed reasons, you should [read this](http://wiki.c2.com/?DeepClassHierarchies). But the short version: *you should favor composition over inheritance*.